# Android application for SQL 2008 database

Tags: android, sql

I am a SQL dba and new to Android. Is it possible to develop an android application which interacts with SQL server 2008 database (remotely) and monitor the happenings? such as agent jobs, event logs, disk space etc

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What are you asking?

Comment: Thanks Campbell. I want to develop a android application so that i can monitor my SQL database through my mobile phone. can you tell me the pre-requisites and how to start with?

Answer (score 2):

Create a set of WCF services on the server. You might want to use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) to interact with SQL Server. Query WCF from your Android device.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669764/how-to-consume-wcf-service-with-android) should get you started.

Not sure, but you might also consider checking 3rd party tools like [SQL Centre Pro](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/sql-centre-pro_lqim.html)

OR create a set of web pages to do the job and access them from your Android device.

See also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757335/how-to-monitor-sql-server-agent-job-info-in-c) and [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/c761e6ac-e023-4c70-8d35-12c541e2baac)

Comment: Many Thanks Sebastian. We actually dont want to create as webpages. what are the software pre-requisities for the first option?

Comment: Just as I said - you can expose pretty much everything through web services, and an Android application can consume them (see the link in my answer to see, how to consume WCF services in Android). These services should retrieve the information that you need from SQL Server instance(s). SMO (see another link in my answer) is one of the methods available to query SQL Server for information.