# How can I create a grid of SQL Jobs for multiple servers?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-job

I am trying to figure out a way to monitor SQL Jobs on multiple SQL Servers and add the details to a web form.  I have done this with App Pools, Services, and Tasks but now I need to monitor jobs as well.  I have a grid that I have created to store things like job name, run time, run date, status, etc.

I found this Question:

[How to monitor SQL Server Agent Job info in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757335/how-to-monitor-sql-server-agent-job-info-in-c)

```
string sqlJobQuery = "select j.job_id, j.name, j.enabled, jh.run_status," +
" js.last_outcome_message, jh.run_date, jh.step_name, jh.run_time" +
" from sysjobs j left join sysjobhistory jh on (j.job_id = jh.job_id)" +
" left join sysjobservers js on (j.job_id = js.job_id)" +
" where jh.run_date = (select Max(run_date) from sysjobhistory)" +
" and jh.run_time = (select Max(run_time) from sysjobhistory)";
```

His query looks good but I need to join one more table from my database (dbo.Monitor) which includes a server IP so I can monitor multiple servers.  I have tried adding LEFT JOIN Monitor.dbo.SQLJobs in multiple places but it never works.  Here is the query I am running:

```
@serverIP       nvarchar(20),
@JobID          nvarchar(100)

SELECT Monitor.dbo.SQLJobs.ServerIP, msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id, msdb.dbo.sysjobs.name, 
msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.run_date, msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.run_time, msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.run_status, msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
ON (msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.job_id)
WHERE Monitor.dbo.SQLJobs.ServerIP = @serverIP
AND msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id = @JobID
AND msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.run_date = (SELECT MAX(run_date) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory)
AND msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.run_time = (SELECT MAX(run_time) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory)
AND msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory.step_name <> '(Job outcome)'
```

Where could I add the other JOIN to make this query work?  Please let me know if I need to add any more information before down voting me.

Comment: I don't know if anyone is interested in the solution but I have figured it out.

Comment: could you please share your solution with us?

Comment: Matt please post the solution if you have figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I have not checked this in a while.  My query would not work because I am trying to query sys jobs on two servers in different domains.

I had to link the servers in order to get data from sys jobs from both servers and display the data in one form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx