# what is the best way to run Sql Agent job using C#?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-agent-job

I am using Sql server 2005 and using C#/Asp.Net 4.0 for UI. 
I want to trigger the sql job from an user action in a webpage. I need to keep checking job's status while its running. There are several old threads on this issue  which gets the status of the jobs ([How to monitor SQL Server Agent Job info in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757335/how-to-monitor-sql-server-agent-job-info-in-c-sharp)) but i need my program should be able to Run,Stop,Enable,Disable the jobs

I need the below functionality in my UI.

1. Check the status of a sql job
2. Run the specified job
3. Stop the job
4. Disable/Enable the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following system stored procedures:

[sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) - start an Agent job
[sp_stop_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182793%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) - stop an Agent job
[sp_update_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188745%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) - enable/disable an Agent job

**Update:**
If you really want to use SMO instead, best place to check out is [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job_members%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). The Job class allows you to do all this.

Comment: Thanks thats right! I wanted to try for Server management object library to manage these operations. any idea about that?

Comment: Why do you want to use SMO to call a stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. my research also tells me that i can go with simple sp calling rather than going for SMO.